# How to make ajax load posts from the current category?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I made ajax loading posts when clicking on the button, I want to know how to output posts from the current category, and not all of them. Now all records are displayed, I do not know how to fix it. Can you tell me exactly how to make ajax loading posts from the current category, and not all in a row

Example.php

```
  <?php
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'paged' => 1,
    'cat' =>  array($category),
    
);
$blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="example-container">
        <?php while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $blog_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="season-item">
            <div class="serial__preview">
                <a class="serial__poster" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img loading="lazy" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/play.svg" class="serial__play" alt="">
                    <img loading="lazy" class="serial__img" src="<?php echo the_field('миниатюра'); ?>" alt="">
                    <p>52:00</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="serial__text">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="serial__number"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            </div>
        </div>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="loadmore">Load More...</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Function.php

```
function blog_scripts() {
    // Register the script
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
 
    // Localize the script with new data
    $script_data_array = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'load_more_posts' ),
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-script', 'blog', $script_data_array );
 
    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blog_scripts' );
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
    
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
     $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '2',
        'cat' =>  array($category),
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
 
    <?php if ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $blog_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="season-item">
                <div class="serial__preview">
                    <a class="serial__poster" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img loading="lazy" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/play.svg" class="serial__play" alt="">
                        <img loading="lazy" class="serial__img" src="<?php echo the_field('миниатюра'); ?>" alt="">
                        <p>52:00</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="serial__text">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="serial__number"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php
    endif;
 
    wp_die();
}
```

Custom.js

```
var page = 2;
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': blog.security
        };
 
        $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if($.trim(response) != '') {
                $('.example-container').append(response);
                page++;
            } else {
                $('.loadmore').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the current category to load more buttons.

```
<div class="loadmore" data-cat-id="<?php echo $category[0]->cat_ID; ?>">Load More...</div>
```

Now you have to pass that id to ajax on click.

```
var data = {
    'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
    'page': page,
    'security': blog.security,
    'cat_id': $(this).data('cat-id')
};
```

in your ajax callback get that id and pass it to WP_query args.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '2',
    'cat' =>  array($_POST['cat_id']),
    'paged' => $paged,
);
```

**Updated as per OP code.**

**Example.php**

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'paged' => 1,
    'cat' =>  $category,
    
);
$blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="example-container">
        <?php while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $blog_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="season-item">
            <div class="serial__preview">
                <a class="serial__poster" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img loading="lazy" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/play.svg" class="serial__play" alt="">
                    <img loading="lazy" class="serial__img" src="<?php echo the_field('миниатюра'); ?>" alt="">
                    <p>52:00</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="serial__text">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="serial__number"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            </div>
        </div>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="loadmore" data-cat-id="<?php echo $category; ?>">Load More...</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Function.php**

```
function blog_scripts() {
    // Register the script
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
 
    // Localize the script with new data
    $script_data_array = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'load_more_posts' ),
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-script', 'blog', $script_data_array );
 
    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blog_scripts' );
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
    
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
     $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '2',
        'cat' =>  $_POST['cat_id'],
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
 
    <?php if ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $blog_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="season-item">
                <div class="serial__preview">
                    <a class="serial__poster" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img loading="lazy" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/play.svg" class="serial__play" alt="">
                        <img loading="lazy" class="serial__img" src="<?php echo the_field('миниатюра'); ?>" alt="">
                        <p>52:00</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="serial__text">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="serial__number"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php
    endif;
 
    wp_die();
}
```

**Custom.js**

```
var page = 2;
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': blog.security,
            'cat_id': $(this).data('cat-id')
        };
 
        $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if($.trim(response) != '') {
                $('.example-container').append(response);
                page++;
            } else {
                $('.loadmore').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried to add this to custom.js, function.php and example.php, but loading posts from the current category doesn't work, maybe ajax loading just doesn't work for me

Comment: did you print what you got in `$_POST['cat_id']`?

Comment: sry, I'm not very good at php, did what you wrote

Comment: can you share the site link?

Comment: sorry i cant, i am using local site, there is only the code i wrote in the question. Thanks for trying to help, I will try to change my code

Comment: wow it really works! but he duplicates some posts, I understood what the problem is. Thank you very much for your work, you are a genius

Comment: duplicated due to the fact that I had a different number of posts in the array, thanks again